# MS ACCESS SQL DELETE ERROR

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm working on my thesis. My topic is about Inventory System.

The problem is, my codes doesn't work. Hoping you could help me guys.

```
string DeleteFile = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Mac\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\ThesisDatabase.accdb";
string DeleteCode = "DELETE FROM COLLEGE WHERE Staff LIKE '" + StaffName+ "' AND SupplementalSeminar LIKE '" + SSeminar+ "'";
OleDbConnection con2 = new OleDbConnection(DeleteFile);
OleDbCommand com2 = new OleDbCommand(DeleteCode, con2);
con2.Open();
com2.ExecuteNonQuery();
con2.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Delete Success!");
```

StaffName and SSeminar are just strings.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work".  Does it throw and exception and if so what's the message, or does it simply not delete the row or rows you expect it to and if so what are the values of `StaffName` and `SSeminar` and the values of the `Staff` and `SupplementalSeminar` columns in the table for those rows?

Comment: It doesn't throw any Exception. I also tried catching some Exception but nothing happend. 

Sample Values
StaffName: Marcelina, Ascunsion
SSeminar: Advance Reading

Stored ni the database are the same. It's supposed to delete the rows inside the SQL but nothing happend.

Comment: Arrrgggh.  You are doing a thesis in MS Access?

Comment: I'm using MS Access as my SQL Database.

Thanks for all the comments. I found out where my error was.

Comment: Then you can delete the question.